# WSO2 ESB secure API with HTTP Basic

Tags: api, authentication, wso2, esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and I have implemented the authentication handler suggested by WSO2 documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs?src=search
When the incoming user isn't authenticated successfully the piece of code that should return an error to the client is executed:

```
                headersMap.clear();
                axis2MessageContext.setProperty("HTTP_SC", "403");
                axis2MessageContext.setProperty("NO_ENTITY_BODY", new Boolean("true"));
                messageContext.setProperty("RESPONSE", "true");
                messageContext.setTo(null);
                Axis2Sender.sendBack(messageContext);
                return false;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't have any effect, i.e. the unauthenticated user is still able to invoke the API. Does the WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 documentation miss anything here?

Kind regards,

Heiko

Comment: Try the code in the link : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs which works.  [BasicAuthHandler]

Comment: Sorry, but the example above has been taken from the link you have quoted. I have now worked around the problem as follows: Instead of executing the code snip above I'm putting a property into the message context indicating whether authentication was successful. This property is than evaluated in a sequence of my API and returns an authentication error if the authentication has faild.